# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AND Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Tags: jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

As in the title, I have one spring-mvc application which runs on both VMs.

My application needs to deal with large number of message import(I used a blocking executor, kept both `queue` and `threadPool` size very small). And I set the same JVM options for these 2 VMs. The benchmarks are as below:

1. **JVM**: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, **OS**: Linux(3.8.0-42-generic),   **Architecture**: amd64 64bit.
2. **JVM**: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, **OS**:Windows 7 (6.1), **Architecture**: amd64 64bit.

But the result turns out to be quite different, on my `windows` VM, I can run the MessageImport procedure as I want and never run into some `OutOfMemory` error, while on the `linux` VM, there will always be some `memory error` after just several times of import. And from the `JVisualVM`, I could see the used heap just explosed suddendly, `GC` activities increase, it feels like the `VM` is doing some `GC` work.

I've tried to make all the parameters the same on both machine, and now, the only thing different between them seems to be this **JVM**.

So could anyone explain the difference between these two VMs?

**UPDATE**

Here I post 2 image of CPU & Heap by JVisual VM monitor.[image: **CPU**]
[image: **HEAP**]

Does anyone ever encounter the same problem, could anyone give some suggestions please?
If necessary I think I'll start a bounty.

Comment: Have you tried Oracle's hotspot build on Linux? What happens if you give both VMs enough memory where they don't run out of memory in seconds?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I'm trying that now, trying to replace this OpenJDK with Oracle JDK on linux.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann  On my Linux machine, I've replaced the OpenJDK with **Oracle JDK(1.6.0_45)**, and using the latest stable **tomcat server6.0.41**. And I still have the same heap explosion problem. Another difference is that my Linux has **4 CPU**, while the windows has only **2**. Apart from this, I can't find any difference between these 2 machines. Now I'm totally confused, since I thought the problem was **OpenJDK**.

Comment: OpenJDK's more or less the Oracle one.

Comment: This looks like a task that's just using a lot of memory. Trying doing a heap dump with VisualVM.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Thanks. But what I don't understand is that the same procedure is working fine on my windows machine.  I'll check the heap dump

Comment: If I had to guess from this, OS-specific parts of the runtime are causing this, but that's a wild guess.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Thanks very much for your guess. And this is out of my range =.=!. OMG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is also due to synchronization.

Please check my other question if you have a similar problem.

[c3p0 deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199495/c3p0-deadlock-on-refurbishcheckinresourcetask-getconnection)